# Microsoft Band Development

Tags: microsoft-band

I want to add the Background color to the page in tile in the Microsoft Band. I am following the below code to create the tile in the band and to display the white color in background, but I didn't get the white color in page, Please help me to solve this problem.

```
  Guid tileguid = new Guid("C781F673-6D05-4D69-BCFF-EA7E706C3418");
  Guid pageguid = Guid.NewGuid();
  var panel = new FilledPanel
  {
  Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 220, 128),
  BackgroundColor = Colors.White.ToBandColor(),
  };
  var layout = new PageLayout(panel);
  BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileguid)
  {
  Name = "Torch Tile",
  TileIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/ElectricBulb.png"),
  SmallIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/Torchsmaltile.png")};
  tile.PageLayouts.Add(layout);
  await bandclient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile);
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sai Priya. C

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code you're creating the Tile with a page layout (a.k.a. template), but not actually creating an *instance* of a page with that layout.  You need to use the `IBandTileManager.SetPagesAsync()` API to add a page with that layout to the Tile.  See section 8.8.3 of the [Microsoft Band SDK Documentation](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf).

Comment: Actually in my code iam using the below code to add the page with that layout to the tile.                                                                                   await bandclient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(
               tileguid,
               new PageData(pageguid, 0, new FilledButtonData(0, Colors.White.ToBandColor())));                                                                                                                   But i didn't get the background color to the page.

Comment: What *do* you get instead?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, after adding the setpageasync code I got background color in filled panel. But I have one another question I want to add the multiple pages in one tile and add different colors to that page, Please help me to solve this issue.